# twitter4j get tweets by GeoLocation

Tags: java, twitter, geolocation, twitter4j, tweets

I have a task, where I need to get tweets using twitter4j by Geo Location, everything about OAuth and tokens I did correctly, but when I'm trying to create a query getting a problem with method `geoCode();`
During compilation process I'm getting an error :

```
Error:(148, 60) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method geoCode(twitter4j.GeoLocation,double,java.lang.String)
  location: class javax.management.Query
```

I don't understand what is going wrong...
My Query code:

```
double lat = 59.4372155;
double lon = 24.7453688;
double res = 5;
String resUnit = "mi";
QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query().geoCode(new GeoLocation(lat,lon),res, resUnit));
```

If you need any more code, please tell me which part, I will UPDATE the Post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to break it down first and work from there:

```
Query query = new Query().geoCode(new GeoLocation(lat,lon), res, resUnit); 
query.count(11); //You can also set the number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There was a problem , that I did wrong report.I did `import javax.management.Query;` but needed `import twitter4j.Query;`  If you didn't give me your code, will never noticed my attention on it